# Dojo Dijit styling issues

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, tabcontainer

I'm trying to use a `dijit/layout/TabContainer` with a modified dijit theme. I need to modify some of the styling of the `TabContainer` tabs such as the padding of the tabs, boldness, etc. However the styling commands specific to the pages that use the `TabContainer` are not working.

This piece of code is on my home page's CSS file.

```
.myTheme .homeTabContent
{
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

.myTheme .homeTabContent .dijitTab /* The .dijitTab is the original CSS class of the tab*/
{
    font-weight: bold !important;
    padding-left: 3px !important;
    padding-right: 3px !important;
}
```

The tabs' padding and font-weight remain unchanged despite the `!important`. Editing the `TabContainer` CSS file in `myTheme` isn't a practical solution because I that will just mess up the styling of a different page. What happens is that as I load the page with the styling, my commands appear to be working for a split second, however all of that is undone when the `TabContainer` finishes loading. Can anyone tell me why or offer me a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first step in a problem like this is to inspect the misbehaving node in Firebug (or IE's equivalent) and see which styles are applied and what overrides what.

Comment: I did in Firebug. The correct CSS gets applied during loading. But disappears after loading is complete. On Firebug, it never mentions the CSS from the home page's CSS file.

Comment: Then how about posting your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution. http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/rd58M/

I have included class `myTheme` to body tag. Like this

```
<body class="claro myTheme">
```

*I'm not good at english but I will try to explain.*

If you write css like this `.myTheme .homeTabContent .dijitTab` that mean an element of class `homeTabContent`  have to stay inside some element that has class `myTheme`

Like this

```
<body class="claro myTheme">
    <div class="homeTabContent">
        <div class="dijitTab"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But if you write css like this `.myTheme.homeTabContent.dijitTab` (with no space) it will be

```
<div class="myTheme homeTabContent dijitTab"></div>
```